# net user /add leaves a user with empty password?

Tags: windows-10

A user I created on a Windows 10 Pro machine using `net user /add /activate:yes` seems to be able to login without password.  Is that the expected behavior?  If so, what is the proper sequence of commands to avoid this potential security hole?

Comment: Windows does not force user to create an user account with password. In linux systems, a password is must with user account. You can see in the setup, there is no force to set password. Also you can create account password from command prompt using `net user username`. However you can append the password in the command. I don't know, but this is the security model of windows. But in active directory domain environments group policy can be used to force users to create a password for the account in order to log in remotely. Also when you create a Microsoft account, you get more security.

Comment: PS It is not _no password_ it is a _blank_ password. Anything requiring a password MUST be given a blank one or it won't match.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't include a password, then the account is created without one.

Syntax is:  NET USER username password /ADD /ACTIVE:YES [More options] [/DOMAIN]

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is expected behavior. You can simply enter afterwards
`net user [insert user name here]*`, for example `net user Jack*`.

Comment: In a standard configured Windows a  user with a blank password can only log on locally. Cannot log on remotely. There are settings in Group Policy that control this.